# How to prevent Windows Defender from showing "Windows protected your PC" on a published WPF app with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, .net-core, windows-defender

I have developed an app (WPF-Windows Template Studio app with .NET Core 3.1 as the target framework) that I have published, as shown in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceFBf.png).

When I send the .exe to another Windows PC the PC shows the following
[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD7VN.png).

Is there anything I can do as a developer to prevent Windows Defender from showing this dialog? Which option shall I use in the publish dialog instead?

Telling the customers to Click on "Run anyway" is not an option.

Comment: This will depend on the security level of the target PC. I think the only proper way around this is to sign your application.